# apache2: why <LimitExcept> parameter results “deny not allowed here” error in virtualhost tag?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, configuration

I have asked the [same question to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126605/why-limitexcept-parameter-results-deny-not-allowed-here-error-in-virtualhost) but then I thought it might be more related to here.

in apache's httpd.conf between `VirtualHost` tags I put `<LimitExcept>` expression like follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName geopreprod.xxx.com.tr

 <LimitExcept HEAD POST GET>
     Deny from all
 </LimitExcept> 

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://XXXXXXXX...
  ProxyPassReverse / http://XXXXXXXX....
</VirtualHost>
```

and then apache web server fails to start by giving following error:

```
Syntax error on line 513 of XXXXX/httpd.conf:
deny not allowed here
```

Although it says `<LimitExcept>` can be used in `VirtualHost` tag in [offical docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept) why do I get this error?

in apache docs it says:

```
Context:    server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as your `<LimitExcept>` block is within a context that's valid for the `Allow`/`Deny` directives, then it will work just fine.

If you try putting even a naked `Deny` rule directly in the `<VirtualHost>` context, you'll see that it's denied in the same way - `<VirtualHost>` with a `Deny` in it is not allowed, so neither adding a `<LimitExcept>` between them.

But, the trick is that `<LimitExcept>`, and some other block types like `<IfModule>`, do not modify the context of a directive; you'll never see "limit" in the list of acceptable contexts in the documentation for a directive.

There's are only [four contexts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) that can dictate whether a directive is allowed:

- server config
- virtual host
- directory (which includes `<Location>` and `<Files>` type directives, too)
- .htaccess

In the case of the `mod_authz_host` directives (`Order`, `Allow`, and `Deny`), they're allowed only in directory and htaccess contexts, so they'll always error when they're not in one.

In your case, there's no filesystem location for this reverse-proxy vhost, so you'll want to use a `<Location>` block (which is a valid context for `Allow`/`Deny` because it's of the directory context type):

```
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    <LimitExcept HEAD POST GET>
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Oh, and get rid of that `<Proxy *>` block, as it's not doing anything - the `<Location>` takes precedence over it anyway, but it's in conflict with the `<LimitExcept>`'s restrictions.. so it makes me nervous.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is saying that `Deny` is not allowed in a `<LimitExcept>` block.

From a [different part of the docs:](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny) "The directives provided by mod_authz_host are used in `<Directory>`, `<Files>`, and `<Location>` sections as well as .htaccess files".

Comment: would it behave like I expected if I put `<Directory>` in `<VirtualHost>` and then put `<LimitExcept>` in `<Directory>` ?

Comment: If you still had a `Deny` inside the `<LimitExcept>`, no.  The problem is where you put the `Deny`.

Comment: But when I do like that the server starts without error. Do you think the limit restriction won't work?

Comment: @Ladadadada Actually it'll work when buried in a directory block (or a location block in this case, since there's no directory for a proxy config).  See my answer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.